# Does primeNg upgrade need Angular upgrade?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-turbotable

I am planning to use primeng turbo table feature that is included in `5.x`.

Right now, we are using version `4.3` in our project. When I upgraded primeng to latest version, I came across many issues. Many answers in google suggested to upgrade Angular version accordingly.

I want to confirm if the upgrade of primeNg needs an upgrade of Angular as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the newest [primeng release notes](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6-0-0-released/):

> PrimeNG 6.0.0 is fully compatible with Angular 6 and RxJS 6, if you
>   are using Angular 5 then you need to continue using PrimeNG 5.x
>   instead.

Also [5.0.0 version release is compatible accordingly](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5-0-0-released/):

> PrimeNG 5 fully support Angular 5, if your project is on Angular 4,
>   the PrimeNG version to use would be 4.x as PrimeNG 5 does not work on
>   Angular 4 due to AOT constraints.

So try to always check release notes.

Comment: One would think, that this goes on accordingly. But I don't find any note in the [PrimeNG 7 release notes](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-7-0-0-released/)...

Comment: I was looking for this to make sure I was correct  , thanks

Comment: Can we use PrimeNg 6.1.7 with angular 8, becuase while using PrimeNG 8.0.0 I am getting error in IE11

To see the error in detail please refer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631229/angular-8-2-14-with-primeng-8-0-0-application-not-getting-loaded-in-ie11

Comment: @PrashantAgrawal IE11 is going to be not supported with the newest Angular version, see [here](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#internet-explorer-11) and AFAIK the same support list goes for PrimeNg. Take a look of other packages you use, maybe this error is caused by one of them.

Comment: @mpro I try downgraded my primeNG to 6.1 version, then it was working in IE11

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use PrimeNG 6, then it is fully compatible with angular 6 and you cannot use primeNG 6 with angular 5, you can only use PrimeNG 5 with angular 5.

You can read that here: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6-0-0-released/

If you want to use [PrimeNG 7.0.0](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-7-0-0-released/), then you need to upgrade to angular 7.

The PrimeNG 4.2.3 is compatible with angular 5: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-4-2-2-released/

> So you need to verify the compatible angular version and upgrade to it, when you use a newer version of PrimeNG