# Angular 8.2.14 with PrimeNG 8.0.0, Application not getting loaded in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, primeng

I have recently upgraded from angular 7 to angular 8.2.14, along with the PrimeNG version upgraded to 8.0.0, and the Application working in all the browsers except the internet explorer

Below is my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.29",
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.29",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^7.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^7.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "7.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "7.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "ng-mocks": "^8.1.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap-modal": "^1.0.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "1.5.0",
    "ng2-select": "~1.2.0",
    "ngx-accordion": "0.0.17",
    "ngx-autosize": "^1.2.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "3.2.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^13.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "primeicons": "^3.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "primeng": "^8.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  }
```

And here is my tsconfig.json file

```
 "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "typeRoots": [
          "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
          "es2017",
          "dom"
        ],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
      }
```

Also, removed 'not'in browserlist file.

Getting below-mentioned error in IE11

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved by changing the version of **@angular/cdk** to **"8.2.1"**. Since Datatable Module of PrimeNg uses this internally.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.